# Does Apple allow me to put a link in my App for selling “real-world services” AirBnB- without 30% cut?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, b2b

i develop an free App(iOS), within the App i want to give user 2 Links which redirect them to website in Safari,

1.web-shop that user can buy a new mobile (outside the App, pay )
2.Insurance web-shop which user can insure his smartPhone(out side the App, 
(app only get a message if those contract has been successfully done and user get info about them in the App, but those aren't any service which user can use in App)

- it's a Purchases AirBnB

And user may after opening these site just cancel, or may buy something there .

My question is if i'm allowed to use these links in the App like "insure your Smartphone" - "to Smartphone Shop", and it does't make my app to fail the apple review.

Answer (score 1):

Apple insist on certain industries using their paid/commission based In-App purchasing services, for example Music downloads and Books. This protects their rights and costs in advertising these apps and services for sale through iTunes.

AirBnB and Hotels are not currently on the list of Apple In-App services, so you will not get rejected for that.
Insurance is also not on the list.
You will have to satisfy PCI DSS compliance but if you are running through an existing service providers web browser and not capturing confidential data then you are probably covered.